# How do I draw a border around the text of a JavaFX label?

Tags: css, text, javafx, label

In order to enhance the readability of our text, it has been suggested that we outline the text of label controls. I know you can stroke Text shapes, but we went with Labels. I forget why, but I think it was because there was something a Label could do for us that a Text Shape could not.

How do I go about drawing an outline or a border around the letters and words of a label?

I tried `-fx-stroke` but that didn't work, and `-fx-border` just drew a border around the node. Is there anyway to make this work?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use CSS to specify the outline for your label text.

```
/** file: outline.css (place in same directory as OutlinedLabelText) */    
.label {
    -fx-font-size: 50px;
}

.outline.label .text {
    -fx-fill: lightseagreen;
    -fx-stroke: firebrick;
    -fx-stroke-width: 2px;
}
```

[image: outline]

Sample usage:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class OutlinedLabelText extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Label label = new Label("Outlined");
        label.getStyleClass().add("outline");

        StackPane layout = new StackPane(label);
        layout.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        Scene scene = new Scene(layout, Color.PALEGREEN);
        scene.getStylesheets().addAll(getClass().getResource(
                "outline.css"
        ).toExternalForm());

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

---

The above sample is using an undocumented selector to select the text for styling from the label.  Usually, the [JavaFX CSS documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#labeled) for complex nodes that are parent nodes containing child nodes includes a section for the child nodes in a section of the documentation titled "Substructure".  For [Labeled](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#labeled), the substructure is not provided, but if it were, it would read something like below:

> **Substructure**
>
> - text — the text node within the Labeled

I found out the `.text` selector using a scene graph introspection tool such as [ScenicView](http://fxexperience.com/scenic-view/).  For Java 9 the JavaFX implementation sets the style class in code in the class constructor for the following class: `com.sun.javafx.scene.control.LabeledText`, where it invokes `getStyleClass().addAll("text");`.  So anyway, that is where the somewhat magically appearing subcomponent class `.text` originates from.